# How to start docker container as server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, lxc

I would like to run a docker container that hosts a simple web application, however I do not understand how to design/run the image as a server. For example:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

This will start and immediately shutdown the container. Instead we can start it interactively:

```
docker run -i -p 80:80 ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

This works, but now I have to keep open the interactive shell for every container that is running? I would rather just start it and have it running in the background. A hack would be using a command that never returns:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 {image} tail -F /var/log/kern.log
```

But now I cannot connect to the shell anymore, to inspect what is going on if the application is acting up.

Is there a way to start the container in the background (as we would do for a vm), in a way that allows for attaching/detaching a shell from the host? Or am I completely missing the point?

Comment: You could mount a folder from your host machine to /var/log in order to have easy access to the container's logs: docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /tmp/log:/var/log {image} /foregroundapp

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The final argument to `docker run` is the command to run within the container. When you run `docker run -d -p 80:80 ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash`, you're running `bash` in the container and nothing more. You actually want to run your web application in a container and to keep that container alive, so you should do `docker run -d -p 80:80 ubuntu:14.04 /path/to/yourapp`.

But your application probably depends on some configuration in order to run. If it reads its configuration from environment variables, you can use the `-e key=value` arguments with `docker run`. If your application needs a configuration file to be in place, you should probably use a `Dockerfile` to set up the configuration first.

[This article](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) provides a nice complete example of running a node application in a container.

Comment: I think the problem is that my application is already deamonised (it uses the standard apache2 from ubuntu in the container).

Comment: Ahh, so you just need to run apache in the foreground as your command.

Comment: Well, I have all my environment variables setup and sure my application would run the way you described. However, what the point of dockerfile if I need to manually start my application when running docker container. I want to put all steps inside the docker file and only what user of my image has to do is to launch it.

Answer (score 8):

Users of docker tend to assume a container to be a complete a VM, while the docker design concept is more focused on optimal containerization rather than mimic the VM within a container.

Both are correct, however some implementation details are not easy to get familiar with in the beginning.  I am trying to summarize some implementation difference in a way that is easier to understand.

1. **SSH**

   SSH would be the most straight-forward way to go inside a Linux VM (or container), however many dockerized templates do not have ssh server installed. I believe this is because of optimization & security reasons for the container.
2. **`docker attach`**

   docker attach can be handy if working as out-of-the-box.  However, as of writing it [is not stable](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8521) (edit: the issue is now closed). Might be associated with SSH set up, but not sure when it is completely fixed.
3. **docker recommended practices** (nsenter and etc)

   Some alternatives (or best practices in some sense) recommended by Docker at https://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/

   This practice basically separates out mutable elements out of a container and maps them to some places in a docker host, so they can be manipulated from outside of container and/or persisted.  Could be a good practice in production environment, but not now when more docker related projects are around dev and staging environment.
4. **bash command line**

   "`docker exec -it {container id} bash`" cloud be very handy and practical tool to get into the machine.
5. **Some basics**

   - "`docker run`" creates a new container so previous changes will not be saved.
   - "`docker start`" will start an existing container so previous changes will still be in the container, however you need to find the correct container-id among many with a same image-id.  Need to "`docker commit`" to suppress versions if wanted.
   - Ctrl-C will stop the container when exiting.  You will want to append "`&`" at the end so the container can run background and gives you the prompt when hitting enter key.

Answer (score 4):

To the original question, you can tail some file, like you mentioned, to keep the process running.

To reach the shell, instead of "attach", you have two options:

1. `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`

Or

2. run ssh daemon in the container, port map the ssh and then ssh to container.

Comment: this is not what I want to do. Sure I can login to container and run my server ... however it is not my objective. Container has to start with my server running without any additional steps. I do not want to login to container every time it is launched and launch my server. This should be automated.

Comment: @StanSokolov looks like you miss-understood. The server is started with the container as daemon. Later if you want to login to the shell, you have the above two options.